# Loading multiple sheets within for loop causes script to freeze (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have had this issue multiple times and was wondering if I am doing something wrong. Here is my code:

```
function createPersonalSheet() {
var persons = new Array("KDS", "BH");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AtZdrPVig0OadFZjZlYxOEI3WVBwS1NfN2cwMlpaNWc");

for(j=0;j=1;j++) {      
  var data = getData(persons[j]);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(persons[j])
  var end = sheet.getMaxRows()-3;
  var range = sheet.getRange(4, 2, end, 14);
  range.clearContent();
  var range = sheet.getRange(4, 2, data.length, data[0].length);
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

It runs if I only add one value in the persons array, but as soon as I add a second, the script stops working and it even crashes the spreadsheet (I have to refresh). Any ideas? I tried Utilities.sleep(1000) at the end of the for loop to give it some time but no effect.

Any help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Can you share a dummy spreadsheet with the function in it? I'd like to see the error. I have a feeling it has to do with your loop and setting j=1.

Comment: why did you hard code the loop length ? try `for(var j=0;j<persons.length;j++)`  and the pause in the loop was a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming when you have only one element in the array you were doing:

```
for(j=0;j=0;j++) {
```

that would work because that says j starts at 0 and while it equals 0, increment j.

when you add the second element

```
   for(j=0;j=1;j++) {
```

Now you have a problem - j starts at 0 and while it equals 1, increment j.  That doesn't make any sense.

also, even if that was your intent, the boolean portion of the for statement (the second part) would have had to be **j==** for the equality operator not **j=** for the assignment operator.  That mistake can crash apps scripts.

Serge's idea was correct.  use

```
for(var j=0;j<persons.length;j++)
```